# Using "stepSize" and "stepStartValue" together

Tags: chart.js

I've started to use chart.js library, and I face an issue when using the following properties : 
stepSize and stepStartValue.
Used alone, each one runs well. But used together, it seems like stepStartValue is just ignored and only stepSize is taken into account...

I use google chrome as a web browser, and I don't get any error message in the java script console of it...

Below the code where I "deal" with these two properties (ticks section of the left yAxes) :

```
options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
         yAxes: [
             {    
                 id: 'A',
                 type: 'linear',
                 position: 'left',
                 ticks: {
                      stepStartValue : 6,
                      stepSize: 3
                 }
             },
             {
                  id: 'B',
                  type: 'linear',
                  position: 'right',
                  ticks: {
                      min: -10,
                      max: 10
                  }
              }
```

If someone could help !-)...
Thanks.